# How can I move variables between batch programs

Tags: batch-file

I would like to know how to send a variable set in one batch file to another. So for example I have:

**program.bat**

```
@echo off
set /p amount="Amount:"
set a=0
set /p text="Text:"
:loop
set /a a+=1
start myecho.bat
if %a% LSS %amount%
exit
```

And now the second program named `myecho.bat` which will show variable `text` from the first `program.bat`

Comment: Wow, this is very unclear, I am not even joking, please clarify quickly before this gets closed.

Comment: ok, so firstly, never ever call batch files the same as actual windows commands, in this case choose something other than  echo` So as an example, you would need to send the variable to the next batch and catch it in the next batch. So for instance in in command.bat do `myecho.bat %text%` and in second batch do `echo %~1 & pause`

Comment: After renaming your file, send it as argument to `file.bat` file.

Comment: Your question, regardless of any edit made since voted to be closed is still off topic. The reason is that technically there is nothing wrong with the script you've posted. This site is for helping you to fix your coding issues, not to tell you how to write it at the outset. Anyhow, as your issue seems basic, I'd suggest you just change **`start`** to **`Call`**.

Comment: @Compo or else exit the `myecho.bat` with `exit /b`.

Comment: How about `start call`?

Comment: whats the diffrence between start and start call?

Comment: Using `start` for a new window only. See [here](https://www.robvanderwoude.com/call.php) and [here](https://ss64.com/nt/call.html).

Comment: `if %a% LSS %amount%` should probably be `if %a% LSS %amount% goto :loop`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<kbd>**[• Update •](https://superuser.com/a/1528545/969781)**</kbd>   There is **another way to do this**, by write **variables in bat it self**, and use **another bat to read this 1st bat with variables**.

> 1. by use reg add / reg query ( setx )

You can use **`setx`** to do this, but, the value from **`setx`**

only will be available after next *instance/session* at the time this is set, by cmd/powershell

Also, **`setx`** can be set by using **`reg add`**:

By Reg Add: `reg add HKCU\Environment /v _amount /d "%amount%" /f`

By Setx: `setx _amount "%amount%"`

For read the value before next *instance/session*:

```bat
for /f "tokens=3 delims=^ " %%i in ('reg query HKCU\Environment ^| findstr /i /c:"_amount"') do set _amount=%%i
```

So, in another *instance/session, the variable are in system, just do if need: **set amount=%_amount%**

```bat
@echo off
set /p amount="Amount:"
setx _amount "%amount%"
set a=0
set /p text="Text:"
:loop
set /a a+=1

start myecho.bat 

:: add this lines lines if ..( ...)  in file "myecho.bat" :: 
if "./%_amount%/." equ ".//." (

     for /f "tokens=3 delims=^ " %%i in ('reg query HKCU\Environment ^| findstr /i /c:"_amount"') do set _amount=%%i
     
     ) else (
     
     set amount=%_amount%
     
     )
  
  if %a% LSS %amount% echo/ do some thing
  exit
```

When no more need the variable, you can able to delete/remove setx/reg key by:

**`reg delete HKCU\Environment /v _amount /f 2>nul >nul`**

> 2. by use a file txt to save and read...

*Write value by 1st bat in %temp%\file.txt and read by 2nd bat:*

```bat
@echo off
set /p amount="Amount:"
echo/%amount%>"%temp%\amount_value_in.txt"
set a=0
set /p text="Text:"
:loop
set /a a+=1

start myecho.bat 

:: add this lines lines if ..( ...)  in file "myecho.bat" :: 
 
set /p amount=<"%temp%\amount_value_in.txt"
  
if %a% LSS %amount% echo/ do some thing
 
exit
```

> 3. by send variable to direct with start file.bat %amount% ...

```bat
@echo off
set /p amount="Amount:"
echo/%amount%>"%temp%\amount_value_in.txt"
set a=0
set /p text="Text:"
:loop
set /a a+=1

start myecho.bat %amount% 

:: add this lines lines if ..( ...)  in file "myecho.bat" :: 
set amount=%1      
if %a% LSS %amount% echo/ do some thing
exit
```

**Obs.:**

1- Sorry my limited *English*

2- You can replace *start* by *call*

Comment: @montonero  Also, code updated to use in same session/instance, again, thank you so much..

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use the variable in your second batch file (*as long as you call it from your first one* because the `call`ed process runs in the same environment / inherits the environment in a `start`ed process).

first.bat:

```
@echo off
set "test=Hello"
call second.bat
```

second.bat:

```
echo variable 'test' is: %test%
```

If you want to pass the value of the variable, better use a parameter:

first.bat:

```
@echo off
set "test=Hello"
call second.bat %test%
REM that's the same as:
call second.bat Hello
```

second.bat:

```
@echo off
echo parameter is: %1
```

(see `call /?` for use of parameters)

(both examples run with `call` or `start`)

Comment: @maxmarsz: just out of curiosity... which variant did help you better?